# App Keeps Pinging GPS

Tags: android, gps, locationlistener

I have a `mapView` activity that has a `LocationListener` registered to check for a new location every two seconds.  When I press the back button to go back to the main screen of the app the GPS continues to check for a location every two seconds.  Does the listener not get stopped when the `Activity` stops?  If not how can I handle this?  I currently have not overridden `onStop()`.

```
private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        updateWithNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        //TODO do something to handle when the provider is disabled
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override the `onPause` method of your `Activity` because that is sure to be called. 
In the `onPause` method you should unregister the `LocationListener`.

You do this through

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(yourListener);
```

If you have a `mapView` I sometimes had the problems with the `locationOverlay` keeping a listener registered and using the GPS even if the mapview was in the background.